# Why is one of the transactions for my token account missing from my wallet in Solana Explorer?

Tags: spl-token-program, associated-token-account, explorers

I have a [wallet `5FHwkrdxntdK24hgQU8qgBjn35Y1zwhz1GZwCkP2UJnM`](https://explorer.solana.com/address/5FHwkrdxntdK24hgQU8qgBjn35Y1zwhz1GZwCkP2UJnM?cluster=mainnet) that [has a token account `Tig6ugKWyQqyRgs8CeDCuC3AaenQzRJ5eVpmT5bboDc`](https://explorer.solana.com/address/Tig6ugKWyQqyRgs8CeDCuC3AaenQzRJ5eVpmT5bboDc?cluster=mainnet).

I can see the transaction [`F3YdjJSsAE8rDrMFwSrmf7P8vZSMfVvKBrY9C612td1gM6eqZdZSbTM723bwDmMS2j5mYNrPwJgFc64Ra79Wyr5` on my token account](https://explorer.solana.com/address/Tig6ugKWyQqyRgs8CeDCuC3AaenQzRJ5eVpmT5bboDc?cluster=mainnet) - where I received 50 USDC tokens (it's at the bottom, 7 days ago):

[image]

However unusually, this transaction [does not show up on my wallet](https://explorer.solana.com/address/5FHwkrdxntdK24hgQU8qgBjn35Y1zwhz1GZwCkP2UJnM?cluster=mainnet): Other token transactions, however, do.

[image]

**Why can't I see this transaction on my wallet?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other three transactions in your screenshot are outgoing (send) transactions. Whereas F3Y transaction is an incoming (receive) transaction.

When you interact with the SPL program, it  uses the token accounts to transfer tokens. In receive transaction, your wallet address is not used as an account in the transaction. That's why it doesn't show up on the explorer when you search your wallet.

However, when you send the tokens, you have to sign the transaction with your wallet, which means even your wallet address is used as an input in the transaction along with the token address. So send transactions will reflect when you search your wallet on the explorer.

Comment: Thanks @tsar! I know about ATAs, but I previously thought searching a wallet would also return token transactions precisely because of the thing you mention in your third paragraph - outgoing token transactions show up because the parent wallet was signing them. Your answer makes things much clearer.